# R optimization: minimize quadratic function

Tags: r, optimization

I have a task to minimize 2 similar quadratic functions for `beta`.

For example:

```
K <- matrix(data = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
                 2, 16, 2, 1, 2, 
                 1, 2, 8, 2, 1,
                 2, 1, 2, 16, 2,
                 1, 2, 1, 2, 32),
        nrow = 5, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE)

 k <- c(-2, 4, 12, 0, 2)
```

1. First:
   [image]

Where `lambda` is multiplier for penalty function.

I am using `optim` to solve this problem:

```
minimize <- function(beta){
value <- (1/2)*(t(beta)%*%K%*%beta) - t(k)%*%beta + 0.1*abs(sum(beta)-n_s) # lambda = 0.1
return(value)
}
betta2 = optim(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), minimize)
betta2$par
```

Which method in `optim` should I use for better and faster optimization?

2. Second:
   [image]
   With condition:

[image]

Where `n_s` and `epsilon` are known constants.

In other words, I have constrained and unconstrained minimization tasks.

I know, I can find a solution of second task using `solve.QP`, but constraints there might be only linear.

For example, I can minimize my second task using `solve.QP`:

```
 betta = solve.QP(K, k, K, k, meq = 0, factorized = FALSE)
```

But I can't add my special constraints there (and I don't really like this solution):

```
A <- matrix(1:1, ncol = 5)
n_s = 5
epsilon = 0.1
betta = solve.QP(K, k, A, c(-(n_s*epsilon + n_s)), meq = 0, factorized = FALSE) # gets an error: Amat and dvec are incompatible!
```

How could I correctly use `optim` (or maybe another?) function to solve my constraint optimization problem (with my special constraint)? Which method should I choose for it?

Comment: Can you add some code of what you have tried?

Comment: @SantiagoI.Hurtado did it

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the following approach :

```
library(DEoptim)

K <- matrix(data = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
                     2, 16, 2, 1, 2, 
                     1, 2, 8, 2, 1,
                     2, 1, 2, 16, 2,
                     1, 2, 1, 2, 32),
            nrow = 5, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE)

k <- c(-2, 4, 12, 0, 2)
n_s <- 5
epsilon <- 0.1

minimize <- function(beta)
{
  if(abs(sum(beta) - n_s) < (n_s * epsilon))
  {
    value <- (1 / 2) * (t(beta) %*% K %*% beta) - t(k) %*% beta 
    return(value)
    
  }else
  {
    return(10 ^ 30)
  }
}

obj_DEoptim <- DEoptim(fn = minimize, lower = rep(-100, 5), upper = rep(100, 5),
                       control = list(itermax = 50000))

obj_DEoptim$optim
$bestmem
       par1        par2        par3        par4        par5 
 2.46187682  0.08787879  2.00000001 -0.17878788  0.12903226 

$bestval
[1] 4.577542

$nfeval
[1] 100002

$iter
[1] 50000
```